# An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user. org..InternalAuthenticationServiceException: null

Tags: java, mysql, spring

everybody. Please, can someone exaplian me why am I getting error from this method.

```
private List<GrantedAuthority> getUserAuthority(Set<Role> userRoles) {
    Set<GrantedAuthority> roles = new HashSet<>();
    for (Role role : userRoles) {
        roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
    }
    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>(roles);
    return grantedAuthorities;
}
```

And this is the output.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.example.onlineshop.service.MyUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(MyUserDetailsService.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
at com.example.onlineshop.service.MyUserDetailsService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ff4e4457.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:771) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:749) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
at com.example.onlineshop.service.MyUserDetailsService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$817b5d14.loadUserByUsername(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:108) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
```

I was doing a login with mysql.

This is the implementation of `MyUserDetailsService`:

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String name) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userService.findUserByName(name);
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getUserAuthority(user.getRoles());
        return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getUserAuthority(Set<Role> userRoles) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> roles = new HashSet<>();
        for (Role role : userRoles) {
            roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>(roles);
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }

    private UserDetails buildUserForAuthentication(User user,
                                               List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
            user.getName(), user.getPassword(), user.getActive(),
            true, true, true,
            authorities);
   }
}
```

Comment: According to the logs, you got the exception in line 29 in the method `loadUserByUsername` of `MyUserDetailsService`. Can you post its implementation?

Comment: @MohammadAlAlwa Thank you. Here is my MyUserDetailsService class

Answer (score 2):

Most likely when the result of this call is null (ex. non existent user)

```
User user = userService.findUserByName(name)
```

Then, a null pointer exception will be thrown in the following line when you call `user.getRoles()`

```
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getUserAuthority(user.getRoles());
```

You can handle this in multiple ways, for example:

```
User user = userService.findUserByName(name);
if (user == null)
   throw new UsernameNotFoundException(name + " doesn't exist");
List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getUserAuthority(user.getRoles());
return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
```